# Is it possible to give a negative prompt with Lexica Image Generation

Tags: image, artificial-intelligence, endpoint

Trying to make a discord version of Lexica AI Image Gen with python. On the website you can give a prompt and then if you want a negative prompt. I'm wondering if the api can do negative prompt because im not seeing anything.

https://lexica.art/

https://lexica.art/api/v1/search?q= -- prompt goes after =

I tried putting the negative prompt with the prompt and that did not work. Also tried to look it up and thats there only endpoint.